# How to apply the solution of helper columns to a full excel file?

Tags: excel

[How to rewrite excel formulas in a readable manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713913/how-to-rewrite-excel-formulas-in-a-readable-manner)

I have got nice answers explaining how to make it using a helper columns. my question is how to do it for `20K` cells as fast and efficient as possible.

Comment: wasn't it possible to just copy down the formulas of the helper columns?! I don't quite understand which problem is there left for you? Would you mind making this a complete stand-alone question?

Comment: my suggestion in that thread didn't use any helper columns - you could put that formula in a single cell and "fill down" - to do that quickly for 20,000 cells (assuming no blanks) you can use the "fill-handle" - black "+" on bottom right of cell. Double-click that and formula will fill down as far as you have continuous data in adjacent column

Comment: @barryhoudini can you please make it as an answer and with more details? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested this formula in your original question

```
=IF(ISERROR(G16&G17),X16,IF(OR(G16={"xxx","yyy","zzz"}), 

Y16,IF(G16="333","N\A",IF(G17="333",Z16,MAX(0,(HEX2DEC(IF(D17="",W$10,W17))-

HEX2DEC(W16))/VLOOKUP(F16,$M$36:$N$41,2,0))))))
```

If you enter that in a column adjacent to some existing data then you can fill down to the end of the data with one double-click.

Put cursor on the bottom right of the cell with the formula until you see a black

"+". That's the "fill-handle". Double-click on that and the formula will "fill down" as far as you have data in an adjacent column